# Is the fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ special, in the following sense?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$
be the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$
where $d\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$
is square-free.

Is $d=2$
the only value for $d$
such that the fundamental unit of $K$
is of the form $1+\sqrt d$?

Comment: See also [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions)

Comment: I had that question myself some time ago. I thought about fundamental units of the form $2 + \sqrt d$, then $3 + \sqrt d$ and $4 + \sqrt d$. The pattern became obvious to me then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\mathrm{Nm}(1+\sqrt{d}) = (1 + \sqrt{d})(1 - \sqrt{d}) = 1-d$$

For this element to even be  a *unit*, let alone a fundamental one, you must have $1 - d = \pm 1$.